# Convert table from landscape to portrait

Tags: tables, multirow, wrap

I am unable to make a table in portrait because I have some large col headings (some with hyphenated words) that don't wrap. The only way I could create this table was by making it in landscape orientation.
Please point out how to modify my code so that I can make the table below in portrait orientation.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{This is my table and I hope you can help me improve                 
it. How do I make it in portrait?}
\label{tab:testtab}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth} {p{1.4cm}|p{1cm}p{2.9cm}p{3.5cm}|p{1cm}p{2.9cm}p{3.5cm}|p{2cm}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}[2]{1.4cm} {Col group (years)} & \multicolumn{3}{c} 
{{\textbf{Location one}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{{\textbf{Location two}}} & 
\multirow{2}[2]{2.6cm}{\textbf{Combined conditionX-      associated SOME cases}}\\
 & SOME cases & Percent positive for conditionX & conditionX-associated SOME cases & SOME cases & Percent positive for conditionX & conditionX-associated SOME cases & \\
\midrule 0-$<$1  & 455 & 10.4 (15/144) & 47  & 381 & 10.0 (2/20) & 38 & 86 (25\%)\\
1-4     & 376 & 10.9 (19/175) & 41  & 256 & 20.8 (10/48)& 53 & 94 (28\%)\\
5-15    & 91  & 10.0 (1/10)   & 9   & 157 & 30.0 (3/10) & 47 & 56 (17\%)\\
16-24   &     &                &    & 91  & 12.0 (3/25) & 11 & 11 (3\%)\\
25-49   &     &                &    & 244 & 11.4 (8/70) & 28 & 28 (8\%)\\
50-64   &     &                &    & 280 & 10.0 (3/30) & 28 & 28 (8\%)\\
$\geq$65 &    &                &    & 334 & 11.1 (5/45) & 37 & 37 (11\%)\\ 
\hline
Total   & 922 & 10.6 (35/329) & 97 & 1,743& 13.7 (34/248) &     242 & 340                 
(100\%)\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: Not a good looking table!]

To convert this table to portrait I need columns 3 and 4 to wrap (text should display in 3 lines not 2). Once that is done the last column would look alright (ie., text should spread over 4 lines).
Note: I listed several packages used elsewhere in the document. Hope someone can help.

Comment: I also need contents for cols 2-7 centered horizontally and vertically. Cells that have a fraction in parenthesis need to be on the same line as the preceding number. Thanks!

Comment: Do please provide information about the page size and margin widths.

Comment: A4 page. I am using \usepackage{geometry} as follows:
\geometry{includehead}
\geometry{hmargin={3.5cm,2.3cm}}
\geometry{vmargin={1.6cm,2.5cm}}
\geometry{headheight=15pt}
\sloppy
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Instead of guessing the column widths of the `p` columns, measure them out using `\settowidth` instructions. There are four separate widths to calculate.
- Since you wish to use a `tabular*` environment, set the `\tabcolsep` parameter to `0pt` and let LaTeX figure out the amounts of intercolumn whitespace by providing the directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.
- Provide more visual structure in the table's header. Use `\cmidrule` directives.
- Don't use vertical lines in the table. They're not needed.
- Last I checked, `47 + 38 \ne 86`, and `97 + 242 \ne 340`.  :-)
- Write `conditionX- associated` instead of `conditionX-associated`. That way, a line break is still possible after `conditionX-` in the headers of columns 4, 7, and 8 even though you've suppressed hyphenation.
- Incidentally, I believe it's highly questionable to suppress all hyphenation and then restore some semblance of decent typesetting via the `\sloppy` directive. If you really can't abide hyphenation, just make the entire document `\raggedright` and live with the consequences. For that matter, what's so awful about hyphenation that makes you willing to abandon decent typesetting output?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includehead,headheight=15pt,
          hmargin={3.5cm,2.3cm},vmargin={1.6cm,2.5cm}} 
\sloppy %% highly questionable!
%\hyphenation{}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
% Measure four separate column widths:
\newlength\lena  \settowidth{\lena}{(years)}
\newlength\lenb  \settowidth{\lenb}{SOME}
\newlength\lenc  \settowidth{\lenc}{10.9 (19/175)}
\newlength\lend  \settowidth{\lend}{SOME cases}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{This table now fits in portrait mode}
\label{tab:testtab}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    P{\lena} P{\lenb}P{\lenc}P{\lend}
             P{\lenb}P{\lenc}P{\lend} P{\lend} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Location one} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Location two} 
& Combined\\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-8} 
Col group (years) 
 & SOME cases 
 & Percent positive for conditionX 
 & conditionX- associated SOME cases 
 & SOME cases 
 & Percent positive for conditionX 
 & conditionX- associated SOME cases 
 & conditionX- associated SOME cases \\
\midrule 
0--$<$1  & 455 & 10.4 (15/144) & 47 & 381 & 10.0 (2/20) & 38 & 86 (25\%)\\
1--4     & 376 & 10.9 (19/175) & 41 & 256 & 20.8 (10/48)& 53 & 94 (28\%)\\
5--15    &  91 & 10.0 (1/10)   &  9 & 157 & 30.0 (3/10) & 47 & 56 (17\%)\\
16--24   &     &               &    &  91 & 12.0 (3/25) & 11 & 11 (3\%)\\
25--49   &     &               &    & 244 & 11.4 (8/70) & 28 & 28 (8\%)\\
50--64   &     &               &    & 280 & 10.0 (3/30) & 28 & 28 (8\%)\\
$\geq$65 &     &               &    & 334 & 11.1 (5/45) & 37 & 37 (11\%)\\
\midrule
Total    & 922 & 10.6 (35/329) & 97 &1,743&13.7 (34/248)&242 &340 (100\%) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico. I didn't know I had suppressed hyphenation. Where did I do that? PS:Thanks for picking up on the maths issue. I had decimals that were rounded incorrectly

Comment: @epdnm - The instructions `\hyphenpenalty=10000` and `\exhyphenpenalty=10000` serve to make hyphenation (essentially) infinitely costly during the paragraph building phase. As a result, very few hyphenations will occur; as you've discovered, not even `conditionX-associated` will get line-broken. The `\sloppy` directive would appear to serve mainly to suppress all sorts of warnings TeX would issue about underfull lines and over-stretched interword spaces. Incidentally, it's never a good idea to include TeX directives in the preamble if one doesn't have a good sense of what these directives do.

Comment: I see. The use of tabular* is not compulsory for me, if you suggest i use something else to simplify this code, i would be more than happy to try it. I've been using LaTeX for only a few weeks, hence, this clumsy code (and the use of directives that help me once but hinder me later on). In the table you created, how can I have the heading for col 1 covering 4 lines (not 3) & how to remove line under 'Combined'?

Comment: @epdnm - Think what `\cmidrule(l){8-8}` might do...

Comment: Hi @Mico to get closer to what I am after I had to 'mangle' your work a bit. To get the headings in first and last columns centered across 4 rows I used: \multirow{4}{1.6cm}{Col group (years)}   
 also:                                                                                                                        & \multirow{4}{2.7cm}{Combined conditionX- associated SOME cases}\\         then: \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} %but no separation between this hline and previous is achieved...So what would be the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: @epdnm - Assuming you're using a `tabular*` environment, did you maybe omit the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive while keeping the `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` directive?

Comment: Doing both of those made no difference to the midrule which also intrudes into the last col a bit. How can I 'shrink' this    '\cmidrule{2-4} and this     \cmidrule{5-7} ?

Comment: @epdnm - It sounds like you did the exact opposite of what I was suggesting you do. Anyway, have you tried "trimming" the cmidrules on the left and right? Give `\cmidrule(lr){2-4}` and `\cmidrule(lr){5-7}` a try.

Comment: cmirrule trim worked. thanks. re your previous comment I tried removing `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` while keeping `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` and also tried the opposite. None of these had the desired effect. Thanks again for following up!

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion: swap rows and columns and add some colour.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, caption, array, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\sisetup{range-phrase=--}
\caption{Table in portrait – rows and columns are swapped}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Col group (years)}\\
\addlinespace
\numrange[range-phrase=\,--\textless]{0}{1} & \numrange{1}{4} & \numrange{5}{15} & \numrange{16}{24}
& \numrange{25}{49} & \numrange{50}{64} & $\geq 65$ & \textbf{Total} \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!50! Lavender}\multicolumn{8}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Location one}}\\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{SOME cases}\\
555 & 376 & 91 & & & & & 922 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{ 8}{@{}l}{Percent positive for conditionX}\\
\makecell{10.4 \\ (15/144) } & \makecell{10.9\\ (19/175)} & \makecell{10.0 \\ (1/10)} & & & & & \makecell{10.6\\ (35/329)} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{ConditionX-associated SOME cases} \\
47 & 41 & 9 \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!50! Lavender}\multicolumn{ 8}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Location two}} \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{SOME cases}\\
381 & 256 & 157 & 91 & 244 & 280 & 334 & 1{,}743 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{Percent positive for conditionX}\\
\makecell{10.0 \\ (2/20)} & \makecell{20.8 \\ (10/48) } & \makecell{30.0\\ (3/10)} & \makecell{12.0\\ (3/25)}& \makecell{11.4\\ (8/70)} & \makecell{10.0 \\ (3/30)} & \makecell{11.1\\ (5/45)} & \makecell{13.7\\ (34/248)} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{ConditionX-associated SOME cases} \\
38 & 53 & 47 & 11 & 28 & 28 & 37 & 242 \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
\rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!50! Lavender}\multicolumn{ 8}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Combined conditionX-associated SOME cases}} \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
 \makecell{86\\ (25\,\%)} & \makecell{94\\ (28\,\%)} & \makecell{56 \\ (17\,\%)} & \makecell{11 \\ (3\,\%)} & \makecell{28 \\ (8\,\%)} & \makecell\\{28 (8\,\%)} & \makecell{37 \\ (11\,\%)} & \makecell{340 \\ (100\,\%)} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, I also wanted to use background colour for rows but I get 3 error messages when I do saying that the package xcolor has already been loaded with options. Adding the global options: ,svgnames, table
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this. However, I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Is siunitx really needed?

Comment: siunitx is not really needed here – it just slightly simplifies the code (in particular for spacing problems. You also may code, say $16\textendash24$. For the options conflict you may either  write `\documentclass[svgnames, table, other options]{report}`  or add to your preamble `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,table}{xcolor}`. B.t.w., with the `table` option, needless to load `colortbl`.